# Page breaks in table rows

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I want to make a document that contains a synopsis of events, like

```
YEAR           HISTORY          CULTURE             SCIENCE

1770        History para-     culture para-      science para-
            graph history     graph culture      graph science
            paragraph.        paragraph cult-    paragraph sci-
                              re paragraph.      ence paragraph
            History para-                        science para-
            graph history     culture para-      graph science
            paragraph his-    graph culture      paragraph.
            tory paragraph    paragraph
            History para-     
            graph.

1771        History para-     culture para-      science para-
            graph history     graph culture      graph science
            paragraph...      paragraph ...      ence ...
```

I tried to use a `longtable` to achieve such a result, but run into the problem that `longtables` do not allow page breaks within cells, but only inbetween rows. In my example, page breaks are only possible between the 1770 and 1771 row, but not for example, if one of the rows itself becomes too long for one page.

The text of the paragraphs comes from a database and is automatically assembled. So manual adjustments are not an option.

Exists there any alternative for `longtables` that allows page breaks inside a row, or is there any other way to achieve such a layout without using tables?

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`parcolumns` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns). Here is a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{parcolumns}% http://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns
\begin{document}
\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,colwidths={1=2cm}]{4}
% Headings
\colchunk[1]{YEAR}
\colchunk[2]{\centering HISTORY}
\colchunk[3]{\centering CULTURE}
\colchunk[4]{\centering SCIENCE}
\colplacechunks

% Content
\colchunk[1]{\noindent 1770}
\colchunk[2]{\noindent\lipsum[1-3]}
\colchunk[3]{\noindent\lipsum[4-6]}
\colchunk[4]{\noindent\lipsum[7-9]}
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

Columns are constructed using `\colchunk[<column>]{<stuff>}` and placed using `\colplacechunks`. If you don't specify `<column>` it's sequentially filled.

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) (for dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style) and [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) (for document layout) was used as an illustration in this example.

Comment: Or `parallel` package!

Comment: @HarishKumar: No, the OP wants more than 2 columns.

Comment: Additional note: If one wants to use colours, one must load `pdfparcolumns` instead from the `oberdiek` bundle, which loads loads `parcolumns` and patches some macros.

Comment: I meant `pdfcolparcolumns`.