# Line spacing in parcolumns environment

Tags: line-spacing, parcolumns

Is it possible to change the line spacing within a `colchunk` in a `parcolumns` environment?  I tried the following without success:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}       
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\normalsize

\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent]{2}
\colchunk[1]{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\colchunk[2]{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}\footnotesize This works not. This works not. This works not. This works not. This works not. This works not. This works not. This works not. This works not. This works not. \par}
\colplacechunks
\end{parcolumns}

{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}\footnotesize This works fine. This works fine. This works fine. This works fine. This works fine. This works fine. This works fine. This works fine. This works fine. This works fine. \par}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would have been better, if you had pointed to your question [Page breaks in table rows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54823/page-breaks-in-table-rows) or stated, that you are interested in more than two columns with different column sizes.

Comment: @Speravir Since multiple columns or different column sizes aren't an issue in the `parcolumns`environment, all this was irrelevant for the original question. It is only relevant for Keks Dose's recommendation of the `paracol` package.

Comment: But Keks ;-) would have known before, so you misleaded him.

Answer (score 11):

What the package is doing is splitting each column up line by line and then re-assembling the page a line at a time constructing each line out of the lines from the columns, so the final result is even line spacing and the line spacing in the original column settings is necessarily lost

If you don't do that then you have to work a lot harder if you want to allow page breaks at arbitrary points mid-paragraph as if the columns have different line spacing there may not be any feasible break points in general.

So while it is possible to devise a parallel markup system that allows different spacing, probably `parcolumns` should not be your starting point for that as you would have to change almost the entire package.

---

It seems that the OP wants columns of different sizes. It seems that the `paracol` package supports that so long as you don't try to be too tricky with floating environments (which would need to be restricted to columns of the same width)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol, blindtext, setspace}
\begin{document}

% EDIT: Space between columns:
\setlength{\columnsep}{24pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\normalsize

\begin{paracol}{2}
\showthe\columnwidth
\advance\columnwidth 5em \hsize\columnwidth
  \blindtext
\switchcolumn
\advance\columnwidth-10em \hsize\columnwidth
\begin{spacing}{1}
  \blindtext
\end{spacing}

\end{paracol}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\showthe\columnwidth
\advance\columnwidth 5em \hsize\columnwidth
  a a a a a a a\blindtext
\switchcolumn
\advance\columnwidth-10em \hsize\columnwidth
\begin{spacing}{1}
  b b b b b b b \blindtext
\end{spacing}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If nobody comes up with a better answer, David deserves the bounty -- at least (Thank you, David) -- he had a look into the source code!

Comment: I don't understand your edited version, but it works and I will test it during the next months. I hope, Dieter, who asked, is as content as I am. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You are right, it does not work with parcolumn. I did not check using the parallel-package, however, it works this way using the paracol-package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol, blindtext, setspace}
\begin{document}

% EDIT: Space between columns:
\setlength{\columnsep}{24pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\normalsize

\begin{paracol}{2}
  \blindtext
\switchcolumn
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}%
\begin{spacing}{1}
  \blindtext
\end{spacing}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

## WIZARD NEEDED!

**As the comments below show, there is no easy way to change the width of the columns!** The maintainer of paracol has documented the implementation broadly, but I fail to understand it. Regarding the `columnwidth` he says in section 2.1.3:

> \hsize is TEX’s primitive register to have the width of a page or a column-page being built.
>   It is let be \columnwidth by \paracol, while \pcol@mctext and \endparacol let it be
>   \textwidth.

Äh, hmpf, whut? Would anybody else give us a hand?

Comment: The `paracol` package would be fine for me if a method exists to assign different width to the columns. Alas, skimming over the manual I couldn't find a hint that this is possible. Any ideas?

The `parallel` package is no alternative for me, because I might need more than two columns.

Comment: @Dieter I've amendet my example: you can alter the length `\columnsep`.

Comment: Is it also possible to change the width of the two columns? At the moment their width is equal. I need a smaller left column.

Comment: @Dieter No idea, we need a wizard here who implements the function, or you ask the maintainer of paracol by email.

Comment: Where did you read the cited phrase? It’s not part of `paracol-man.pdf` for version 1.0, which now is in MiKTeX and AFAIS in TeXlive, too.

Comment: @Speravir See here: http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/ There is paracol.dtx, including "impl.dtx". Do as described in README and you'll get the implementation docu.

Comment: What I understand: At `\paracol` = `\begin{paracol}` will be defined `\let\hsize=\columnwidth`; at `\endparacol` = `\end{paracol}` and at `\pcol@mctext` will be defined `\let\hsize=\textwidth`.

Comment: +1,  I added a version of this document with a wider 1st column and narrower second column to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer Keks Dose posted doesn't work for me on LuaLaTeX or LaTeX (dvi or pdf). The right column narrows (like you'd expect from reducing the `\columnwidth`), but it doesn't actually move to the right, so the output overlaps with the left column. I managed to get it working using `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` instead of adjusting the `\columnwidth` primitive directly.

You pretty much have to invoke the `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` macros each time you use `\switchcolumn` unless they're both set to zero, or you won't get the correct result.

A much simplified example is posted below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol, blindtext}

\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}

\begin{document}
  \begin{paracol}{2}

    \leftskip=0em \rightskip=-5em
      WIDENED LEFT COLUMN \blindtext

    \switchcolumn

    \leftskip=5em \rightskip=0em
      NARROWED RIGHT COLUMN \blindtext

    \switchcolumn* % To keep paragraphs vertically aligned

    \leftskip=0em \rightskip=0em
      NORMAL LEFT COLUMN \blindtext

    \switchcolumn

    \leftskip=0em \rightskip=0em
      NORMAL RIGHT COLUMN \blindtext

  \end{paracol}    
\end{document}
```

I would have made an edit or a comment, but I don't have enough reputation. :\