# Longtable with items

Tags: longtable

I have a long table which spans several pages. For some unknown reasons to me since I have itemized stuff in my table, it cannot break them into pages. Also the spacing between the items are still wider than what I want. Here is what I have got:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{ p{7.5cm} p{4.5cm} p{2cm} }
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Here is the caption}
\label{Table:table_label}\\
\hline \hline
\textbf{{\small Title1}} & \textbf{{\small Title2}} & \textbf{{\small Title3}} \\
\hline \hline

\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \hline
\textbf{{\small Title1}} & \textbf{{\small Title2}} & \textbf{{\small Title3}} \\
\hline \hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

{\small item1}
\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\diamond}
    \item {\footnotesize subitem1.1}
    \item {\footnotesize subitem1.2}
    \item {\footnotesize subitem1.3}
    \item {\footnotesize subitem1.4}
         \begin{itemize}
         \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\ast$}
             \item {\footnotesize subsubitem1.4.1}
         \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize} & {\small Data1} & \textbf{{\small No1}} \\
\hline
{\small item2} & {\small Data2} & \textbf{{\small No2}} \\
\hline
{\small item3}
\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\diamond$}
    \item {\footnotesize subitem3.1}
    \item {\footnotesize subitem3.2}
    \item {\footnotesize subitem3.3}
    \item {\footnotesize subitem3.4}
    \item {\footnotesize subitem3.5}
    \item {\footnotesize subitem3.6}
\end{itemize} & {\small Data3} & \textbf{{\small No3}} \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for providing some code- could you turn it into a *complete* [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? `longtable` can break a `table` across pages, but will not break a *cell*, regardless of its contents (text, itemize, etc); you might like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54823/page-breaks-in-table-rows

Comment: longtable only breaks _between_ the rows of the table, a cell never breaks. You need to put each item into a separate row of the table rather than use a list or (better usually) just use a list and don't use longtable.

Comment: Never use `center` around `longtable`

Answer (score 4):

9 times out of 10 it's better to set this sort of thing as a list than as a table, which allows a lot more flexibility, and allows page breaking within items, a basic start might be:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\diamond$}
\newcommand\foo[3]{\item[{%
\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
\hrule
\vspace{2pt}%
\makebox[.5\linewidth][c]{#1}%
\makebox[.3\linewidth][c]{#2}%
\makebox[.2\linewidth][c]{#3}%
\endgraf
\vspace{2pt}%
\hrule}}]\par\mbox{}}


\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\foo{item1}{Data1}{No1}
\begin{itemize}
    \item  subitem1.1
    \item  subitem1.2
    \item  subitem1.3
    \item  subitem1.4
         \begin{itemize}
             \item subsubitem1.4.1
         \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\foo{item2}{Data2}{No2}
\begin{itemize}
    \item subitem3.1
    \item subitem3.2
    \item subitem3.3
    \item subitem3.4
    \item subitem3.5
    \item subitem3.6
\end{itemize}
\end{description}


\end{document}
```